# NoReverseMatch at /job_category/IT/

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Reverse for `'job_category'` with keyword arguments `'{'id': <Category: Government>}'` not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: `['job_category/(?P<category_slug>[^/]+)/$']`

```html
{% extends 'base1.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div class="left col-sm-4" style="float:left; width: 360px;">
        <h6 class="p-2" style="background:#A9CCE3; color:#2F4F4F;">JOB CATEGORIES</h6>
        <ul class="list-group">
            {% for x in categories %}
            <li class="list-group-item c1 list-group-item-action" style="color: rgb(2,96,170);">
                <a href="{{ x.get_absolute_path }}"></a>
                    <div class="p-2">
                        <h7 class="card-title">
                            {{x.name}}
                        </h7>
                    </div>
                    <div class="overlay1"></div>
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
</div>


<div class="right col-sm-8" style="float: right; width:825px;">
        <!--{% if category %}{{category.name}}{% endif %} !-->
        <div class="row container-fluid">
            {% for job in jobs %}
            <div class="col-sm-3 mt-3">
                <div class="card c1">
                    <div class="overlay1"></div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title" style="color: rgb(2,96,170);">
                            {{job.post}}</h5>
                        <h6 class="card-text" style="color: rgb(85, 85, 85);">
                            {{job.job_id.comp_name}}</h6>
                        <p><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt mr-1"></i>{{job.address}}<i
                                class="far fa-calendar-alt ml-3 mr-1"></i>{{job.todate|date:'d M, Y'}}</p>
                        <a href="{% url 'job_detail' job.job_id.id %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm right"
                           style="position:relative; float:right;">View more</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

views.py:

```py
def job_category(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    job_requirements = []
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    jobs = Job.objects.all()
    if category_slug:
        category = Category.objects.get(slug=category_slug)
        print(category.slug)
        jobs = Job.objects.filter(job_category=category.slug)
        for job in jobs:
            job_requirements.append(JobRequirements.objects.get(job_id=job))
    return render(request, 'JobCategory/category.html', {'categories': categories,
                                                         'jobs': job_requirements})
```

urls.py:

```py
path('job_category/<str:category_slug>/', views.job_category, name='job_category'),
```

Models.py:

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=4, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_path(self):
        return reverse('job_category', kwargs={'category_slug': self.slug})
```

> I've been trying to filter my page category wise. I cannot find where my mistake is at and can't simply decode this error message. I'm very new to this. Please help!

(Update) Traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /job_category/IT/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\RECRUIT\Home\views.py", line 33, in job_category
    'jobs': job_requirements})
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 443, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 87, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 677, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'job_category' with keyword arguments '{'id': <Category: Government>}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['
job_category/(?P<category_slug>[^/]+)/$']
[14/Dec/2020 11:08:58] "GET /job_category/IT/ HTTP/1.1" 500 173336
```

Comment: Post the full traceback. That will help in finding out the root cause of the error.

Comment: @arulmr I've updated my question with a traceback

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by replacing my kwargs 'category_slug' with 'id'. But, I have no clue why it didn't take category_slug as an kwargs.

```
class Category(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
slug = models.CharField(max_length=4, unique=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def get_absolute_path(self):
    return reverse('job_category', kwargs={'id': self.slug})
```

> urls.py

```
path('job_category/<str:id>/', views.job_category, name='job_category')
```

> views.py

```
def job_category(request, id=None):
category = None
job_requirements = []
categories = Category.objects.all()
jobs = Job.objects.all()
if id:
    category = Category.objects.get(slug=id)
    print(category.slug)
    jobs = Job.objects.filter(job_category=category.slug)
    for job in jobs:
        job_requirements.append(JobRequirements.objects.get(job_id=job))
    print(job_requirements)
return render(request, 'JobCategory/category.html', {'categories': categories,
                                                     'jobs': job_requirements})
```